# Angular - Router guard with one page for multiple outlets

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I was wondering if there is a way to use Angular Route Guard in such way, that it will display same component/page for multiple `<router-outlet>` within code?

The issue is, that I have multiple routing files which utilize nested outlets on different levels. It's an admin application designed to handle lots of tables on different pages and levels. Something like this.

```html
<!-- MAIN WRAPPER -->
<app-component>
  <navbar>
   <!-- Nav list loop -->
   <nav-item [requiredGrant]="item.grant"></nav-item>
   <!-- Nav list loop -->
  </navbar>
  <router-outlet name="main"></router-outlet>
</app-component>

<!-- NESTED MODULE -->
<nested-level-one>
  <sub-menu>
   <!-- Sub-menu list loop -->
   <menu-item [requiredGrant]="item.grant"></menu-item>
   <!-- Sub-menu list loop -->
  </sub-menu>
  <router-outlet name="sub"></router-outlet>
</nested-level-one>


<!-- DEEP NESTED MODULE -->
<nested-level-two>
  <side-menu>
   <!-- Side menu list loop -->
   <side-menu-item [requiredGrant]="item.grant"></menu-item>
   <!-- Side menu list loop -->
  </side-menu>
  <router-outlet name="last"></router-outlet>
</nested-level-two>
```

All the routes, on all levels,  utilize the same `GrandsGuard` which checks if user has the `${DOMAIN}_VIEW` grant or a mix of it. And how "deep" the user gets with his grants determinates where to show Missing Grants Page.

```
MAIN -> Missing Grant (User sees only main navigation and Missing Grant Page)
MAIN -> NESTED -> Missing grant (Main + Sub nav and Missing Grant Page)
MAIN -> NESTED -> DEEP -> Missing grant (Main + Sub, Side menu and Missing Grant Page)
```

As you can imagine, at the moment I would need to add `missing` page in every routing file in order to navigate to it on a correct level. Is it actually possible to return/navigate from the `GrantsGuard` to a single component or a page in the correct router outlet?. The idea is, that I should see the missing grants page if I navigate directly to some route and see the side menu too, if I have access to other pages from said side menu.

```typescript
canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
  const data = route.data;
  if (data && data['requiredRole']) {
    return data['atLeastOne']
      ? this.authService.checkAtLeastOneGrant(route.data['requiredRole'])
      : this.authService.checkUsersGrant(route.data['requiredRole']);
  } else {
    // Either it doesn't work or I do it wrong
    this.router.navigate(['missing-grant'], { relativeTo: this.current });
    return false;
  }
}
```

I have this strange feeling that there is a simple solution and I'm not realizing it.